white-space: nowrap resizes parent but does not respect scrollbar
I have a sidebar with some text that must not wrap. If the text is too big for the container, I want the container (i.e. the sidebar) to expand. Here is an MVP of the problem:
<html>
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <span>This is some text that must not wrap.</span>
    <div class="etc"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.etc {
/* Just for demo purposes to ensure a scrollbar appears.   */
  height: 200vh;
}

.sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidebar span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

This results in the following:

Adding more text does increase the container width, but it's always short by the width of the scrollbar.
Why does this happen, and how can I fix it? Preferably not by adding a scrollbar width's worth of padding/margin to the right.
For transparency, the actual codebase has more complex markup (see below). In this case, whichever of the p:last-child elements is longest will go underneath the scrollbar (or both if they're of similar length).
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>
            <div>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>This is underneath the scrollbar.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Some text...</p>
                <p>This is also underneath the scrollbar if it's long enough.</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
</body>


I tried to reproduce your bug and it happens the first time I open the web page, but if I refresh the page, it goes away. For some reason this problem won't happen if the element is inside an iframe so it can't be placed inside stackoverflow's code snippet. I think maybe it's a bug in chromium...?

Interesting, it happens every time on Firefox. Here's a JSFiddle (though it is susceptible to the iframe issue you found on Chromium): https://jsfiddle.net/0gbw5jk3/

I just noticed that my original issue (with the more complex markup) actually isn't present in Chromium, only Firefox. This feels like it might be a browser bug, but I'm not sure which browser's behaviour is correct.

This is not new. Either use overflow-y: scroll or padding-right: 18px.

scrollbar-gutter: stable; is probably the least bad option. I suspect the problem is that you can get a circular dependency where adding the scrollbar in the auto width can cause layout changes that mean the scrollbar isn't needed, so it's omitted causing layout changes that mean it is needed.

@Alohci - Thank you, I didn't know about that property. Fits my use case perfectly. Browser support isn't an issue for me as this is an internal tool at our company.

@zer00ne - Thanks, overflow-y: scroll is a good fallback option.

Thanks @zer00ne and @Alohci for your comments, both overflow-y: scroll and scrollbar-gutter: stable work for my use case.
Obligatory caniuse for the latter.
